# Right header links not clickable when adding top drop down menu

Tags: html, css, wordpress, drop-down-menu, hyperlink

My site uses wordpress. I have a right header as seen here http://www.gigster.me and a top centered drop down menu as a plugin for buddypress links. This renders the links on the top right un-clickable. I tried changing the z-index properties of the center tab but it's still not working. The drop down menu is causing the usable area to the right and left of the actual tab/menu to be visible but unusable.

I'm not a coder so i appreciate any help for amateurs like me.

thank you

Ziad

Answer (score 0):

A few options:

1. Set the login section to `display: relative;` and that would push the rest of the page down.
2. Decrease it's z-index and when it loads, set `display: none;` for `.header_right`
3. Decrease the login screen's z-index, but increase it when it's dropped down.

Comment: Thanks 1337, i used the third suggestion. The login tab now has the correct z-index. But how can i change it when it's dropped down? in html or css? Cos the header now is on top. How can i change the z-index property when i click on the tab and the menu expands?

Comment: Right now JS is is used to create the animation of it sliding down the screen. Figure out where that is, and see if you can add a z-index parameter. You can also look to see if a class is added, removed or changed when it's triggered, then write your CSS to change the z-index based on the class change.

Comment: Thank you for your help 1337! Much appreciated.. all the best.